# Django Guardian Permission Error: Argument pk was not passed into view function

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-views, django-guardian

I have a Model called Message that I use django-guardian for object level permission. The idea is that both the `from_user` and `to_user` in a message instance should have the `can_view_message` permission. This function is to display a list of messages with the same message `thread_id` (automatically created when a message was created).

```
@permission_required_or_403('can_view_message', (Message, 'pk', 'pk'))
def message_thread(request, pk):
    selected_message = Message.objects.get(pk=pk)
    threads = Message.objects.filter(thread_id=selected_message.thread_id)

    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'latest_messages': threads,
    })
    return render(request, 'myapp/messages_thread.html', context)
```

The url pattern for this request:
`url(r'^messages/([-_a-z0-9]{1,32})/$', message_views.message_thread),`

Here's the Message Model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='From', related_name='%(class)s_from_user')
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='To', related_name='%(class)s_to_user')
    send_time = models.DateTimeField('Send Time', blank=True)
    msg_content = models.TextField('Message')
    thread_id = models.CharField('Thread', max_length=50, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('can_view_message', 'Can View Message'),
        )
```

I use post_create signal to assign permission:

```
def view_message(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    assign_perm('can_view_message', instance.from_user, instance)
    assign_perm('can_view_message', instance.to_user, instance)

post_save.connect(view_message, sender=Message, dispatch_uid="view_message_permission")
```

However I'm getting the following error but don't really know why:

```
GuardianError at /myapp/messages/13/
Argument pk was not passed into view function
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/messages/13/
Django Version: 1.8.4
Exception Type: GuardianError
Exception Value:    
Argument pk was not passed into view function
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/guardian/decorators.py in _wrapped_view, line 111
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: Update your question with the url pattern for the view.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Thank you so much, with your comment I figured out why! I updated the question too, and going to answer it myself. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [@Burhan Khalid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/790387/burhan-khalid)'s comment, I checked my request url, and it was `url(r'^messages/([-_a-z0-9]{1,32})/$', message_views.message_thread),`

I changed it to `url(r'^messages/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', message_views.message_thread)`, with the pk in the request, now it works perfect.